# использовать html tag при возврате строки в функции C#

Tags: c#, html, css

в таблице в одной из ячеек показываю данные, которые беру из фунцкии **строка + переменная из БД** (расчет времени), *строку необходимо покрасить в красный цвет*,

как добавить html tag например `<span>`, чтобы использовать класс css

или может другие решения бывают  ?

```
private string GetTimeDifference(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
{
    string timeString = "";
    TimeSpan ts = planningDateHeure - DateTime.Now;

    //.....

    if ((int)ts.TotalMinutes < 0)  // опаздыват, красного цвета строка
    {
        timeString = "Опаздывает на : ";
        switch (ts.Days)
        {
            case 0:
                HH = ts.Hours.ToString();
                MM = ts.Minutes.ToString().....;
                return "<span style='background-color:red;'>" + timeString "</span>" + ....;
            default:
                HH = ts.Hours.ToString();
                MM = ts.Minutes.ToString()......;

                if (....) { ..... }
                return "<span style='background-color:red;'>" + timeString "</span>" + ....;
        }
    }
    else // вовремя, то без красного цвета
    {
        timeString = "Прибудет вовремя : ";
        switch (ts.Days)
        {
            case 0:
                HH = ts.Hours.ToString();
                MM = ts.Minutes.ToString().....;
                return timeString......;

            default:
                HH = ts.Hours.ToString();
                MM = ts.Minutes.ToString().....;

                ...
                if (.......)
                    return timeString + .........;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Покрасить где? Что это за приложение? Почему HTML? Да и почему у вас каша из UI и данных в одном месте? Обычно отделяют эти слои, делая в данных, например `bool` или `enum`, по которым в UI уже и строится нужный дизайн вывода.

Comment: говоря на вашем сленге незнаю как "кашу" превратить в аккуратную "стопку блинов", помогите коль отозвались МилЧеловек. у меня таблица на веб приложении блазор, и в моем классе модели я делаю расчет времени, чтоб показать на экране "время прибытия через...". легкий вариант делать расчет времени, время1-время2 в модели добавив перемнную, которой присваиваю строку метода, которая получает из апи/бд эти время1/2. Я вижу, что некрасиво, незнаю как подправить, и плюс мне нужно, чтоб строка наполовину была красной, атк я делаю байндинг в моей странице разор я сразу показываю результат моего метода

Comment: Я не веб разработчик, поэтому не скажу. В вопросе пожалуйста, указывайте все нужные данные, чтоб не пришлось гадать что за проект, ведь не первый день на SO, знаете, как работает. Если интересует как сделал бы я, то в коде, полноценный объект, условно `record Train (string Name, TimeSpan Arrival, TimeSpan Departure) { public TrainStatus TrainStatus {get; private set; } }`, сам статус это простой `enum { Arriving, OnStation, Delayed }`. В этом объекте нужные вычисления статуса, и всего остального, что относится к поезду.

Comment: Ну а в HTML уже делаете нужный дизайн, как вам там захочется, хоть через простые перечисления, а-ля: `Поезд @train.Name @if (train.TrainStatus == TrainStatus.Delayed){<span style='background-color:red;'>Опаздывает на: ...</span>}`. Вот уже как видите, отделили UI от данных, мы не генерируем в C# HTML код, мы просто даем данные, по которым фронт уже делает нужное. Вот в эту сторону и копайте.

Comment: Чтобы строка с кодом html рендерилась именно как html, надо преобразовать строку в объект MarkupString:: <div>@((MarkupString)html)</div> https://metanit.com/sharp/blazor/2.1.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

имхо, куча лишней фигни. я бы сделал примерно так (код подправьте сами:)

```
if ((int)ts.TotalMinutes < 0)  // опаздывает, красного цвета строка
{
    timeString = "<span class='color" + ts.TotalMinutes + "'>Опаздывает на : ";
    switch (ts.Days)
    {
        case 0:
            HH = ts.Hours.ToString();
            MM = ts.Minutes.ToString().....;
            return "<span>" + timeString "</span>" + ....;
        default:
            HH = ts.Hours.ToString();
            MM = ts.Minutes.ToString()......;

            if (....) { ..... }
            return "<span>" + timeString "</span>" + ....;
    }
}
```

и расцветку сделал стилями:

```
span[class^="color-"] > span {color:red} 
/* у опаздывающих ts меньше нуля, класс будет со знаком минус, типа color-17 */
span:not([class^="color-"]) > span {color:black}
```

Это, разумеется, не отменяет того, что вам рекомендовал @EvgeniyZ в комментариях.

Comment: (@)Инквизитор в моей таблице так и выводит эту строку <span.....ляляляля, то есть не понимает html тег. //по поводу обращения по нику ===> странно, что не берет в расчет собачку, если написать слитно и без скобок, то просто строка исчезает

Comment: Значит, вы выводите все как текст, а не формируете HTML.

Comment: ```<GridColumn Field=@nameof(moyaModel.stroka(tasamaya)) HeaderText=@myLocalizer["textStolbca"] Type=ColumnType.String Width="120" DisableHtmlEncode="false"></GridColumn>```

Comment: ```DisableHtmlEncode="false"```ваш комментарий очень уместный и спасибо Вам !